# How to set up SSH key for git on Windows 10 Ubuntu subsystem

Tags: ssh, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the ubuntu bash (subsystem) on windows 10 as my shell. I have a gitlab git repository that I cloned. When I use the git from this shell it is separate from my windows git and I'm unable to make it use my SSH key. It just keeps asking for my user/pass. Note that the SSH key is configured correctly in gitlab.

I place my id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in ~/.ssh/ (ubuntu subsystem path)

Any idea?

Comment: start the ssh-agent with `eval 'ssh-agent -s'` then load your key with `ssh-add`. If files permissions and the key is setup on gitlab this should work.

Comment: @xaa , I tried it before, but it doesn't work. By the way, ssh-add works only with `eval \`ssh-agent -s\`` and not `eval 'ssh-agent -s'` (different quotes char). I'm able to add id_rsa with ssh-add but git still asks for user/pass.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem. I was using an `https://` url for the origin instead of an ssh url (`git@gitlab.com:...`). After switching to an ssh url the ssh key was used.

To view current remotes: `git remote -v`

To switch a remote: `git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:XXXXX`

Answer (score -1):

Use this command:

```
ssh-copy-id username@server.domain.com
```

Change the user to your username, and target to your destination, so it will copy your ssh key to the target system.

Comment: If I understand correctly, ssh-copy-id is for adding the key on the server. I already have the key on the server. I also have it on my device under ~/.ssh/ . The problem here is that the key on my device is not used.

Comment: Thanks @davidbaumann ! Next time I'll be more accurate!

Comment: @Chef then delete your key from the server, maybe it has some formatting problems, if you pasted it manually. this command will do the work for you. :) I had the same issue, and this command did help me out.

Comment: you can also add `-v`, so it will show you the authentication methods it's trying.